# Docusign Embedded Signing - Handling Callback for successful signing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, docusignapi

I am developing a website based on `AngularJS` which interact with API's made on `Django/Python`.

I have an `iframe` which uses `Docusign's Embedded Signing` written on `Python`.

I know about `returnUrl` and the query parameters it has. But what I'm trying to achieve is to **close(remove from DOM)** the `iframe` on successful completion.
Can anyone help me on how to go about on this?

## Docusign

Comment: Just as an FYI, the DocuSign API guide recommends against using an iFrame for embedded signing (specifically if your app will be used on mobile devices):  "Important: DocuSign recommends that you do not use iFrames for embedded operations on mobile devices."  In addition to display issues on mobile devices, some non-mobile browser types might encounter issues when embedding DocuSign in an iFrame b/c of the security restrictions related to the embedded app within the iFrame. I'd always recommend opening the DocuSign session in a new browser/tab, never in an iFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about implementation specifics with the technologies you're using, but perhaps you can implement a similar approach to what I've done before in an ASP.NET app:

1. In the "POST Recipient View" API request to DocuSign, specify **returnUrl** property to specify where DocuSign should redirect to upon completion -- in my example, I'll call this page **DSComplete.aspx**.  So, when the DocuSign session concludes, the iFrame content will render **DSComplete.aspx**.
2. In **DSComplete.aspx**, I then use JavaScript to immediately redirect the "content page" (i.e., the parent page of the iframe) to another destination -- in my example, let's call that destination **DSResults.aspx**. This is what gets us out of the iFrame, and back into just another regular/non-iFrame page. I also pass along (as part of the redirect URL) the full querystring that came from DocuSign to the returnUrl page:

   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Load", "window.parent.location.href = 'DSResults.aspx?" + Request.QueryString.ToString() + "'; ");
3. Finally, in **DSResults.aspx**, I evaluate querystring parameters (especially the **event** parameter that DocuSign used to specify the outcome of the embedded session), and take appropriate action (i.e., display appropriate messaging to the user according to the outcome of the signing session, etc.).

So, regardless of what language you're using, the key is really that the **returnUrl** page needs to immediately redirect the content page (i.e., parent page of the iFrame) to another regular/non-iFrame page (by setting "window.parent.location.href" using JavaScript as described in #2 above), and then that other page actually does the evaluation of the **event** querystring parameter, etc. (#3 above).

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely try this out today itself.

Comment: Good luck. And, if this approach works for you, please do mark this as the answer so that others might benefit from the information in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the `returnUrl` parameter does not support anything besides a standard http/https link. You'll have to make a redirect page that does that action on the back end.

Comment: I understand that. What I'm asking is how to use this to achieve my scenario of closing the iframe