# How do I access the SigningComplete event for an Embedded Docusin View

Tags: docusignapi

So I have a webmethod that is called from JQuery Ajax that build the ViewUrl, like so

```
 ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, viewOptions);
```

I then assign this url tothe sourceof an iframe. I'd like the user to be redirected to an entirelydiferent page (not just the iframe itself) when the user finishes signing the documentand clicks "Finish".

IS there something I missed in the documentation?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844314/docusign-embedded-signing-handling-callback-for-successful-signing

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this through landing pages.

The two locations for these are going to be through your Admin section in either Signing Settings > In-Session Landing Pages or Brands > Destination URLs.